# Adapt font to container size

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, css

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:

I have a lwc that get passed a text and displays it, but when it's too long (being a title I can't truncate it) I'd need to resize it, to make sure the entire text is displayed and fits his container.

How can I do this?

Thanks

---

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class LwcAppStoreTile extends LightningElement {
@api appname;
}
```

HTML + CSS

```
<template>
    <div class="class1">{appname}</div>
</template>

.class1 {
    height: 30px;
    width: 182px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some image with some code what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I added the code, not that makes much difference

Comment: It has fixed width and height. Should it resize horizontally or vertically?

Comment: I need to resize the text, not the container

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways to adjust font-size function to the size of the screen :

1. The most simple is to use the **vw** unit which represent 1/100e of viewport size [(more info)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container):

yourfile.css

> ```
> h1 { font-size: 8vw }
> h2 { font-size: calc(1em + 5vw) }
> ```

2. Use media query in your css : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I don't need the text to resize based on the screen. The text need the fit inside a div with certain dimensions.

Comment: I dont find anything else in case of LWC. I think the best parctice here is to use vw unit. Other way you have external libraries but I personally prefert avoid them as much as possible => https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/#magic-number-it-with-viewport-units